# How to add default VPC to region that had in past classic EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a very old AWS account, where I used to run old classic ec2 instances in the Virginia region. This means this region **does-not** have a default vpc.

How can I add this default vpc from the cli or console?
I tried adding a vpc and making it default for the region - but it didn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc):

> If your account supports EC2-Classic, you cannot use these procedures to create a default VPC in a Region that supports EC2-Classic.

In non-EC2-Classic region, you have the option via the console to create a new default VPC. So you could, for example, create a default VPC in `us-east-2` if you have deleted the one that AWS created for you (as far as I can tell, AWS did create default VPCs even in "classic" accounts).

But the bigger question: why do you want a default VPC? The only benefit that it provides you is pre-filling some fields when you manually create resources.

Comment: Thank you!  The reason is that a lot of tutorials like for Terraform, require a default vpc

Comment: Incorrect answer, based on accurate but incomplete information.  After removing any EC2 Classic resources from the region, you can direct AWS to remove EC2 Classic support entirely for the region... and you then can have a Default VPC.  Another reason for doing this is to peer EC2 with Lightsail, which also requires a Default VPC, so I discussed it in that context: https://serverfault.com/q/818280/153161

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - perhaps you should add this information as the "correct" answer, with instructions for how to "direct AWS" to make these changes (since it's not in the documentation). If you do that, I would be happy to delete this answer.

Comment: "why do you want a default VPC?" In addition to other comments, [Amazon AWS Lightsail VPC Peering ](https://about.lovia.life/docs/infrastructure/mariadb/) also requires default VPC, can't be done with a non-default VPC.

Answer (score 0):

To add default VPC, you need: delete or migrate the resources that you have created for use in EC2-Classic and then convert your existing AWS account to VPC-only, after then all regions will have a default VPC.

more details here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate.html#get-default-vpc-region